# translate text in python (flask) using google translate API

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api

I want to translate text in python (flask) using google vision API , but i get the result not coded into utf-8 format , this is what my console shows :

```
description: "Hair"
score: 0.97888225
topicality: 0.97888225
, mid: "/m/025kyy"
description: "Forehead"
score: 0.93717384
topicality: 0.93717384
, mid: "/m/0f9swq"
description: "Chin"
score: 0.91583067
topicality: 0.91583067
, mid: "/m/01kq3x"
description: "White-collar worker"
score: 0.89593154
topicality: 0.89593154

]
Translation: [mid: &quot;/ m / 03q69&quot; description: score &quot;Hair&quot;: 0,97888225 actualité: 0,97888225, mid: &quot;/ m / 025kyy&quot; description: score &quot;Front&quot;: 0,93717384 actualité: 0,93717384, mid: &quot;/ m / 0f9swq&quot; description : &quot;Menton&quot;: 0,91583067 actualité: 0,91583067, moyen: &quot;/ m / 01kq3x&quot; description: résultat &quot;Ouvrier&quot;: 0,89593154 actualité: 0,89593154, moyen: &quot;/ m / 027n3_&quot; description: &quot;sourcil&quot;: score &quot;Eyebrow&quot;: 0,88577908 actualité: 0.88577908, mid: &quot;/ m / 0ds4x&quot; description: score &quot;Hairstyle&quot;: 0.87970823 actualité: 0.87970823, mid: &quot;/ m / 037p5b&quot; description: score &quot;Cheek&quot;: 0.79947948 actualité: 0.79947948, mid: &quot;/ m / 01xyhv &quot;description: score&quot; Suit &quot;: 0.62281674 actualité: 0.62281674, mid:&quot; / m / 02hrh1q &quot;description: score&quot; Acteur &quot;: 0.5869953 actualité: 0.5869953, mid:&quot; / m / 0vpsd3h &quot;score: score&quot; &quot;Animateur de télévision&quot;: 0.58168304 actualité: 0.58168304]
```

> this is my **function** to use google api to translate the text

```
@app.route('/translate_text', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def translate_text(target='fr'):

    translate_client = translate.Client()
    text = request.form['texttotrans']
    #text = json.dumps(text1)
    str1 = "".join(text)
    result = translate_client.translate(str1,target_language=target)
    print(u'Text: {}'.format(result['input']))
    print(u'Translation: {}'.format(result['translatedText']))
    print(u'Detected source language: {}'.format(result['detectedSourceLanguage']))
    return "Check your console"
```

Answer (score 0):

The translate Client API  treats the input text as html by default. You have to specify that you are inserting plain text in the following way:

```
result = translate_client.translate(str1,target_language=target, format_=’text’)
```